# Array indices must be positive matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB, I have created a triangle, I used the code as below to find all coordinates of x,y.

```
side_1=[linspace(3,5,100);linspace(2,3,100)]
side_2=[linspace(5,4,100);linspace(3,5,100)]
side_3=[linspace(4,3,100);linspace(5,2,100)]
all_coordinates=[side_1,side_2,side_3]
```

I used the code as below to find angles.

```
angles=zeros(300,1);
for i=1:300
angles(i)=atan(all_coordinates(2,i)/all_coordinates(1,i))*180/pi
end
```

Since view point is flatview, y=0, x=angles
I used this code to plot angles.

```
for i = range(length(angles))
scatter(angles(i),0)
end
```

Got error array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Comment: This is not python! `range` in python is not the same as `range` in MATLAB. You need to do create a vector to iterate and assign it to `i`, `i=1:length(angles)`

Comment: This is some basic matlab concepts that you miss here, you should read the ["getting started with matlab" tutorial](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) before trying to code something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the loop but the problem is that you last loop is wrong.
`range(length(angles)) =0`, you should use `for i=1:length(angles)` instead

In addition the two loops are unnecessary. Not sure what you are trying to do with the scatter plot, but you can just write:

```matlab
angles=atan(all_coordinates(2,:)./all_coordinates(1,:))*180/pi

figure
scatter(angles,zeros(1,length(angles)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful.